# Dúvida sobre a utilização do send() em ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A ideia geral da OO é que cada objeto pode reagir de uma jeito diferente a uma mesma mensagem. No ruby, notei que é possível usar o método send() e que todo objeto em Ruby possui esse método.

Então, posso fazer algo como: object.send(:method)

Mas o que eu não entendo é: qual a vantagem de passar um símbolo para o método? Símbolos são imutáveis, e salvam uma chave para o método? no tipo key => value? Ou alocam e deixam na memórias as variáveis utilizadas no método por todo tempo que o programa estiver rodando?

Answer (score 5):

O método `send` permite que você chama métodos em qualquer objeto de maneira dinâmica.

Por exemplo, imagine que você tenha uma class definida da seguinte forma:

```
class Usuario
  def initialize(nome, email)
    @nome = nome
    @email = email
  end

  def nome
    @nome
  end

  def email
    @email
  end
end
```

Esta classe define 3 métodos: um de inicialização (que recebe 2 argumentos: nome e email), e 2 acessores para os atributos nome e email.

Podemos utilizá-la da seguinte maneira:

```
marcos = Usuario.new('Marcos', 'marcos@example.com')

marcos.name # => 'Marcos'
marcos.email # => 'marcos@example.com'
```

O método `send` pode ser utilizado da seguinte maneira:

```
marcos.send(:name) # => "Marcos"
marcos.send(:email) # => "marcos@example.com"
```

Podemos chamar qualquer método do objeto desta maneira:

```
marcos.send(:class) # => Usuario
'100'.send(:to_f) # => 100.0
'Stack Overflow'.send(:upcase) # => "STACK OVERFLOW"
'Stack Overflow'.send(:downcase) # => "stack overflow"
```

Isso permite algumas técnicas interessantes, como chamar um método diferente em um objeto baseado em alguma entrada, sem a necessidade de uma cadeia de `if`'s e `else`'s. Por exemplo, este código:

```
def acessar_atributo_1(nome_atributo)
  if nome_atributo == 'nome'
    objeto.nome
  elsif nome_atributo == 'email'
    objeto.email
  elsif nome_atributo == 'idade'
    objeto.idade
  end
end
```

poderia ser substituído por essa versão muito mais concisa:

```
def acesso_atributo_dinamico(nome_atributo)
  objeto.send(nome_atributo.to_sym) # Convertemos o argumento do tipo String para um Symbol antes de passar adiante
end
```

Esse código porém apresenta uma brecha: a primeira versão (com `if`'s) permitia apenas que os 3 métodos (`nome`, `email` e `idade` fossem acessados); a segunda porém permite que qualquer nome de método passado seja acessado, o que pode ser uma condição indesejada. Uma boa prática é, antes de chamar o método `send`, certificar-se que o argumento passado é o nome de um método o qual devemos permitir o acesso:

```
def acesso_atributo_dinamico(nome_atributo)
  if [:nome, :email, :idade].include?(nome_atributo)
    objeto.send(nome_atributo.to_sym) # Convertemos o argumento do tipo String para um Symbol antes de passar adiante
  end
end
```